# Use List for Pie Graph C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, csv, charts

I'm a bit new to chart controls, and have been trying to figure out how to programmatically set values in a pie chart - then bar chart. I've made progress, and was able to pull data in from a csv- then convert each column to a list.

What I would like to do is ultimately calculate the unique values in the list, apply that for my series (pie chart) and then display the total count for each unique value in the pie chart. (Like a normal Pie Chart).

I'm all ears if anyone has an easier way of doing this -especially just querying the local csv file itself.
This is where I've gotten thus far:

```
     var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\ProgramData\N3RASupportNotifier\Testing.csv"));
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        List<string> listC = new List<string>();
        List<string> listD = new List<string>();
        List<string> listE = new List<string>();
        List<string> listF = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
            listC.Add(values[2]);
            listD.Add(values[3]);
            listE.Add(values[4]);
            listF.Add(values[5]);
```

Comment: which part do you have problems with? counting the unique values? Look into Linq! Or binding a List of numbers to a pie chart? `yourSeries.Points.DataBindY(yourList.ToArray());`

Comment: Hi TaW, Thank you for your reply. I'm having difficulties linking the pie chart to the list I've created. I want to be able to accurately display the percentage of each unique value out of the total row count. I'm going to try the code you've listed above. Thank you!

Comment: Call if you run into problems! You may want to add a few of the input and desired output in the question..!